# Error 500 after rewrite url to load image

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a subdomain **`pics.mysite.com`** that i use to load images, so the src of an image would be something like **`http://pics.mysite.com/image.png`**

When image is loaded the url is rewrited to another folder inside (`pics_files`) where are the files like this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ pics_files/$1 [L,QSA]
```

Works fine, but now i'm having a problem.
If the image doesn't exists it creates an `Internal Server Error - 500`, but i would like to be able to load an "error" image, like `errorImg.png`, but so far i can't.

How can i rewrite the url to that `errorImg.png` if image do not exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace your code with this:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^pics\.mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /errorImg.png [L]

# if valid image file then load it from /pics_files/ directory
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pics_files/$1 -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /pics_files/$1 [L]

# if not-existing image file then load /pics_files/errorImg.png
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pics_files/$1 !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /errorImg.png [L]
```

Comment: thank you, it works fine. But i need to change just one thing. Instead of load the errorImg.png from the pics_folder i need it to be at the root folder (the folder before). I tryed "RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /errorImg.png [L]" but it didn't work!! Thank you very much.

Comment: I'm sorry but there's one thing missing! It works fine if image exists or not, but what if there's no image name like this "http://pics.mysite.com"? I tested and it doesn't work. It should load the error image also! :(

Comment: I didn't understand your last comment.

Comment: If the url is just "http://pics.mysite.com" without the file name at the end, it loads the index file of the root folder and not the error image. What is necessary to change in the .htaccess file? Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/35949/discussion-between-pedro-and-anubhava)

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are capturing the entire URI and routing it into the `pics_files` directory. If the image doesn't exist, the `!-f` condition passes and the URI is rewritten again, so you end up with:

```
/pics_files/pics_files/image.png
```

which doesn't exist, so the URI is rewritten again:

```
/pics_files/pics_files/pics_files/image.png
```

which doesn't exist, so the URI is rewritten again, etc, etc.

Instead of checking if the URI isn't a file or directory as a condition, check that the target image actualy exists:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pics_files%{REQUEST_URI} -f
RewriteRule ^ /pics_files%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer it was very useful. But you didn't said nothing about loading the "error" image :)